# What are the alternatives to close tabs in mobile?

Tags: mobile, web-app, html

I'm using Materialize CSS and I have [Tabs](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html) in my application...
On desktop I put close buttons to close a tab like this:

[image]

But, on mobile that "tab close button" is not functional, 
I think the best way is a "double touch" on the tab to close.

What are the alternatives?

Comment: Hi liwston. You might rephrase your question and ask for suggestions for alternatives, oppose to the *best*.

Comment: like this @Tory?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Could you explain why 'on mobile that "tab close button" is not functional'?

Comment: of course @Alvaro , to make the touch easy, I need set the close button size, to a big button...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like @Daniel mentioned "double tap" may not be intuitive.

If you look at Safari in iOS, they have a **show all tabs** option to manage your tabs easily. Since users are already used to this interaction, you can try this in your app too (low learning curve for users). Even Chrome mobile browser has similar interaction.

[image]

[image]

You can also consider long press anywhere on the tab to list options like close this tab, Close all but this and all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be wary of a "double touch" to close functionality. It's a "hidden" behavior in that it may not be immediately obvious to the end user.

A simple solution might be including the ability to "close" a tab in the body of the tab's content, or in the toolbar of the mobile app. So long as the "close" is clearly specific to the tab.

It may also be worth popping open a mobile browser (google chrome, FF, etc.) and taking note of how they implement multiple tabs and the ability to close them.

Comment: tank you, I was thinking of putting in the context menu, as a long press on .. chrome tabs are not visible, when you want to switch / close you access the tabs screen and navigates between them like a carousel